# SwiftUI - Xcode - Inferring type not possible for VStack

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, vstack, hstack

I am trying to create a simple master/detail app in Xcode.

I want that the detail view is

```
struct EditingView: View
{
    var body: some View {
        var mainVertical: VStack = VStack() //error here
            {
                var previewArea: HStack = HStack()
                {
                    var editorButton: Button = Button()
                    //the same with return editorButton
                    // I have to add other controls, like a WKWebView
                }
                return previewArea
                //this is a simple version, layout will have other stacks with controls inside
        }
        return mainVertical
    }
}
```

but I get

```
Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred
```

The IDE offers me to fix but if I do that, it writes a generic type I have to fill but then other errors come, f.i. if I put AnyView o TupleView.

I would like that it infers everything, what is wrong that it cannot understand?

Comment: Why don't you use `VStack { HStack { ...`?

Comment: It is not SwiftUI code. Start from https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

Comment: @pawello2222 I need to reference that containers and controls, I am from Android where you can do something with them because they are objects.

Comment: @P5music Then please share more code: eg. why and where are you referencing them?

Comment: @pawello2222 I have to use them like in any application, maybe  in SwiftUI I put everything inside the {}?

Comment: SwiftUI elements are not reference-type, they are struct, value-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SwiftUI you usually don't need to reference your controls. You can apply modifiers to them directly in the view.

This is the *preferred* way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("Click me") {
                    // some action
                }
            }
        }
        .background(Color.red) // modify your `VStack`
    }
}
```

Alternatively if needed you can extract controls as separate variables:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let hstack = HStack {
            button
        }
        return VStack {
            hstack
        }
    }

    var button: some View {
        Button("Click me") {
            // some action
        }
    }
}
```

But in the end I definitely recommend you read [Apple SwiftUI tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/)